# SQL Access query VBA: how to gather the record that has the max nbr of subscriptions

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

This is my data:

| id | key | nbr of subs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 10 |
| 1 | XXX | 3 |
| 2 | MNO | 120 |
| 3 | ABC | 5 |
| 3 | FGH | 110 |

I need the key for the record (ID) that has the max nbr of subscriptions:

| id | key | nbr of subs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 10 |
| 2 | MNO | 120 |
| 3 | FGH | 110 |

I don't mind deleting the extra records, or electing the ones I need and insert them into other table. Any ideas?

```
SELECT P.Key, MAX(P.[Nbr of Subcriptions]) 
FROM P
GROUP BY P.Key;
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need correlated subquery. Try below SQL-

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Key, t1.NBR FROM Table1 as t1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Table1.ID, Max(Table1.NBR) AS MaxOfNBR
FROM Table1 GROUP BY Table1.ID) as t2 ON (t1.NBR = t2.MaxOfNBR) AND (t1.ID = t2.ID);
```

[image]

Comment: THank you very much for your help. However, I get a SYntax Error in FROM Clause.  I need to check the syntax for access SQL to make it work.

Comment: Only you need to replace table name and fields name.